# How to do Cumulative sum in Google Sheets with arrayformula()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know that I can get the cumulative sum of a column using `=SUM($A$2:a2)` and simply dragging this formula down. However, I do not like to drag formulas. I find that using arrayformula() is better for making my sheets more dynamic.

For example, instead of using `=vlookup(d1,$a$1:$b,2,false)` and then dragging this formula, I prefer using `=arrayformula(vlookup(offset(d1,0,0,counta(d1:d),1),$a$1:$b,2,false))`. This last formula will give me the desire result without the need to drag the formula plus the added benefit of being dynamic, if I add items to the D column, the vlookup is also extend.

I was wondering if there is a dynamic way to do something similar with a formula that returns the cumulative sum of a column.

I tried something like `=arrayformula(sum($a$2:a))`, but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=scan(,A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,a+c))
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know this function, but it is very interesting. I have found the documentation (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094?hl=en), but could you explain why you pass some of the parameters as empty values? That is not clear to me..

Comment: If you are referring to the `initial_value` of the scan function, in this particular scenario it can be left blank OR explicitly mentioned as *zero*